# how to create customized textBox using libgdx?

Tags: textbox, libgdx

I'm trying to create text box with the background being transparent and lightly colored in the shape of a bubble/cloud/box(like the texts written in comics) in my application using libgdx at a particular position that is taken from the touch by the user(kind of like Facebook tags or the Nokia Lumia city-lens-tags that are visible to the user, but it should have transparent background for the textBox unlike their black background). Is there any way of implementing this kind of a text box in libgdx? Or is it possible by creating my own skin.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are looking for is [TextButton](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextButton.html) which let you apply your own background and text.

you should create your own transparent background (better be 9 patch) and also font (the font is optional you could use libgdx's default maybe it will be enough for you)

after you have your resources you are ready the create your custom TextButton.
this [Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsSkin) will help you go on , it has all the info you need.

Comment: Thankyou! I shall try this approach now.

Comment: Thanks! NinePatch was exactly what I needed. I also found this later (http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/HowtoNinePatch) and this (http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsNinePatch) which was helpful, though outdated - since SkinPacker and TexturePacker have been unified to TexturePacker2 class